# Monerod stuck sync?

Tags: monerod, blockchain

Im trying to sync for about 5 hours its on this block

2017-04-08 18:15:39.304 [P2P6]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:293     [188.22.149.182:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 1283736 -> 1284255 [Your node is 519 blocks (0 days) behind]
SYNCHRONIZATION started

Might be stuck? How should i fix it

Thanks guys..

Comment: type status to see your synchronization percentage. It might just be slow and looks like your 0 days behind. The error message just says there is a new top candidate

Comment: Also, what version are you running? If it's not 0.10.3.1 then highly suggest that you upgrade to the latest.